# Combining two different 2D coordinate points in order to find a 3rd dimension

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm working in a project where I'm working with two cameras that give me the coordinates of a determined object.

The coordinate systems of the two cameras are separated by a known distance (let's say, 100mm), paralel and in the same orientation

What I'm asking is, in a mathematical point of view, how can I infer the depth of the object? Is there a way to find the zz coordinate using this information?

For example:

Cam1: object found at (10, 10)
Cam2: object found at (30, 10)

Comment: This problem is called triangulation. German article: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(Messtechnik)

Comment: Awsome, thank you. I can't read german though. But I will try to find something in English